# VBA - Macro for copy sheets, insert formulas and change row reference by +1

Tags: vba, excel

I have macro for copy one sample sheet. Numbers of sheets copies are based by different sheet values. I need insert different formulas for every copy to specific range, where row number of formula is elevated by +1. Is it possible to do this?

Example what I need:

```
- Sheet1 "=DATA_SELECTED!$N$2"
- Sheet2 "=DATA_SELECTED!$N$3"
- Sheet3 "=DATA_SELECTED!$N$4"
```

This is what I have right now without +1 in formulas.

```
Sub CopySheetsFromAList()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("DATA").Range("A1")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    ws.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C3").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$M$2"
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C4").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$N$2"
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C6").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$K$2"
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C7").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$Y$2"
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetsFromAList()    
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set MyRange = Sheets("DATA").Range("A1")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        ws.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        iRow = iRow + 1
        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Name = MyCell.Value
            .Range("C3").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$M$" & (1 + iRow)
            .Range("C4").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$N$" & (1 + iRow)
            .Range("C6").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$K$" & (1 + iRow)
            .Range("C7").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$Y$" & (1 + iRow)
        End With
    Next MyCell    
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Is it possible to aply this to combinated formula like this?
`"=DATA_SELECTED!$A$2&" / "&DATA_SELECTED!C2"`

Comment: yes. always use `&` to concatenate every _member_ of your string

Comment: `.Range("L3").Formula = "=DATA_SELECTED!$A$" & (1 + iRow) & " / " & "DATA_SELECTED!$C$" & (1 + iRow)` That is not working for me "/" is writed as mathematical division not as text separator. I need that cell look like "40/2" but now shows "20"

Comment: for this latter need I'd go with `.Range("L3").Formula = "=concatenate(offset(DATA_SELECTED!$A$2," & iRow & ",0),""/"",offset(DATA_SELECTED!$C$2," & iRow & ",0))"`